# Angular 8 ctrlKey and metaKey equivalent?

Tags: angular

I have a web application written in Angular 1.x which allows the user to ctrl-click (or cmd-click on Mac) on an anchor link to open it in a new tab. An unmodified click changes the DOM content instead of reloading the page at the new path. The Angular 1.x code looks like:

```
<a ng-click="nav.go(e.path,$event)" href="{{::e.path}}">{{::e.title}}</a>
```

And in the Angular 1.x controller:

```
if (e.ctrlKey == 1 || e.metaKey == 1) {
    // allow page to be opened in a new tab
    return false;
}
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
...continue by doing ajax and DOM replacement instead
```

Now the application is being upgraded to Angular 8, but the Event class does not have ctrlKey or metaKey. Is there an alternate way to detect these two modifiers in Angular 8?

Comment: it not `Event` class but `KeyboardEvent`, then you should have access to your information

Comment: @Yanis-git you're absolutely right. All I needed to do was swap out Event for KeyboardEvent and then I had the attributes and it works as desired. You should put that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

We have ctrlKey and metaKey in MouseEvent. If you receive click event, it is a MouseEvent, so you will have access to hem. Both of them as Boolean.

see this simple example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpqrjr